# Cypher: filter out nodes with certain paths

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Suppose:

1. I have in my Neo4j database, nodes with `SpecialFromLabel` in them.
2. These nodes are connected to `SpecialToLabel` nodes with `SPECIAL_REL` relationship
3. The following paths, therefor, exist: `p = (from: SpecialFromLabel)-[r:SPECIAL_REL]->(to: SpecialToLabel)`
4. Nodes with  `SpecialToLabel` have a property `to_prop` that can have different string values

How can I construct a query that gives me all `from` nodes that have a path: `p=(from: SpecialFromLabel)-[:SPECIAL_REL]->(to: SpecialToLabel)` - **but** those `from` nodes do not have a path to `to` nodes, where `to.to_prop` is in an unwanted values-set?

in pseudocode (not runnable) I want something like this:

```
MATCH (unwanted_from: SpecialFromLabel)-[r:SPECIAL_REL]->(to: SpecialToLabel)
WHERE (to.`to_prop` in $UnwantedValues)
with unwanted_from
MATCH (from: SpecialFromLabel)-[r:SPECIAL_REL]->(to: SpecialToLabel)
WHERE from not in unwanted_from
RETURN from
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach it like this

```
// collect the unwanted endpoints
MATCH (to: SpecialToLabel)
WHERE (to.`to_prop` in $UnwantedValues)
WITH COLLECT(to) AS unwantedEndpoints

// only use the 'from' nodes that do not have a relation to one of the unwantedEndpoints
MATCH p=(from: SpecialFromLabel)-[r:SPECIAL_REL]->(to: SpecialToLabel)
WHERE NONE( n IN [(from)-[:SPECIAL_REL]->(m) | m] WHERE n IN unwantedEndpoints)
RETURN p
```

==== UPDATED , and applied to Movie dataset====

```
// be careful not to re-use the bindings!
MATCH (persons:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) 
WHERE ((m.title in ["Speed Racer"])) 

with collect(m) as excluded  

MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)  
WHERE  none(n in [(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2:Movie)| m2] where n in excluded)  

RETURN DISTINCT p.name,[(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m3:Movie)| m3.title]
ORDER BY p.name
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tested your solution in neo4jsandbox over the Movies db where: SpecialToLabel=Person, SPECIAL_REL=ACTED_IN, SpecialToLabel=Movie, $UnwantedValues = ["Speed Racer"]. Yet, two Person nodes out of 97 nodes have connections to the unwanted movie. those person nodes have the names: "Ben Miles", "Rain" accordingly - I couldn't figure out exactly why though as your NONE condition seem to cover it - any insights?

Comment: I forgot to tag your name in the comment above @Graphileon

Comment: @AsherYartsev  did you check whether the connections you found are also 'ACTED_IN' rels? I know the Movie db contains situations where you vane bothe an 'ACTED_IN` and a `DIRECTED` rel between persons

Comment: I was always matching on ACTED_IN, here's the query: `MATCH (persons:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE ((m.title in ["Speed Racer"]))
with collect(m) as excluded 
MATCH (persons_new:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)

WHERE  none(n in [(persons_new:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)| m] where n in excluded)

RETURN distinct persons_new`

Comment: On the other hand this query worked good: `MATCH (persons:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)
WHERE ((m.title in ["Speed Racer"]))
with collect(persons) as excluded 
MATCH (persons_new:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)

where none(n in [(persons_new:Person)-[a:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)|persons_new] where n in excluded)
return distinct persons_new`  - but in my original problem I prefer not to do so, as `persons` list is much bigger than `m` list when I store it in `excluded`

Comment: @AsherYartsev What is the type of relationships the two nodes (out of 97) have to the unwanted movies?

Comment: `ACTED_IN` - thing is that they also have the same relations to other movies. the other actors that have `ACTED_IN` relation to unwanted movie "Speed Racer" played only in this movie - it might explain why the proposed solution does not filter out actors that played in unwanted "Speed Racer" AND in other movies - perhaps it lets the paths to other movies evaluate to true and return them as well?

Comment: @AsherYartsev  I saw I re-used the bindings a bit too enthusiastically. I updated the answer .. now returning 95 persons and the movies they act in.

Comment: could you please breifly explain why `MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(:Movie)  
WHERE  none(n in [(p)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m2:Movie)| m2] where n in excluded)` works? as I interpret it it does the next: get all `p`s that have any path to `:Movie` node, and filter out `p`s so that only `p`s without a path to "Speed Racer" will survive. what I cannot figure out from the syntax is: how Cypher understands that I'm grouping by a `Person`, checking whether it has any path to "Speed Racer" and filters this `Person` out?

Comment: There is no grouping. The WHERE only returns true for those persons of which none of the ACTED_IN relations point to node in the excluded set

Comment: The MATCH ensures that you are dealing with persons that are actors